# A word (or expression) which means paying someone with counterfeit money?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, colloquialisms, idiom-requests

Just as *shortchange* means cheating someone by giving insufficient money as change, the word I am looking for means *cheating through counterfeit money*.

There are words as simple as *deceive*, *bilk*, *swindle*, *cozen* and others, but I couldn't find a word that means exactly what I need.

Comment: It's crackers to slip a rozzer the dropsy in snide

Comment: @Mr. Shiny: I'm UK ([no spring chicken,](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/no+spring+chicken) with a misspent youth! :) so I understand that anyway, but for the benefit of others you should [include a link](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090623101651AAQBOKm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [*To **shove***](http://www.socialvocabulary.com/defines/shove.html) [[**the queer**](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JRuNMHNcu5cC&pg=PA4788&lpg=PA4788&dq=slang%20%22shove%20the%20queer%22%20%22pass%20counterfeit%20money%22&source=bl&ots=6iCNPNNIkk&sig=QmLY0BwQCIZotb44RpXcQfV_wvE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EM2oU7uOC4jPOfCdgdAK&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=slang%20%22shove%20the%20queer%22%20%22pass%20counterfeit%20money%22&f=false)] *- verb 4. (slang) - To pass (counterfeit money).*

I've not actually come across *"Let's shove that guy"* as a transitive usage meaning *"Let's palm off some dud notes on him"*, but it seems like a small and natural [functional shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_shift) to me.

Answer (score 1):

From *Lexicon balatronicum: A Dictionary of Buckish*, Francis Grose:

> To **smash**. To pass counterfeit money.

From *Dictionary of American Underworld Lingo*, Hyman:

> **push**, v. 2. To pass or issue, especially counterfeit currency or
>   negotiables